# Can I get NEW APP ID and use it for an old APP?

Tags: facebook-social-plugins, app-id

I have some modified apps on a site. Is it possible to create a new APP ID and swap the old ID with the new one? Would the the apps still work or do I have to start from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. You can, however, generate a new secret key.
Or just create a brand new app to get new app id